# Python 3.8 multiprocessing for copying the random on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random, multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import multivariate_normal

F = multivariate_normal(np.zeros(3), np.eye(3), (3, 5))

def test(k):
    print(k)
    res = np.zeros((5, 3))
    for i in range(3):
        res[:, i] = F[k, :, i]
        #print(res[:, i])
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(cpu_count()) as pool:
        result = pool.map(test, range(3))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    result = np.array(results)
```

In python3.6, the result is equal to the random matrix F. But their two matrices are different in python 3.8. This is just an example. In the real code, I want to pick up each column of F in each time step and do some operations on it.

Answer (score 0):

Psychic debugging: You're running on Windows (any Python version) or macOS (Python 3.8 or later, which would explain the discrepancy between 3.6 and 3.8 on the same machine), both of which default to the `'spawn'` method of making worker processes, rather than `'fork'` (the default on pre-3.8 macOS and still the default on UNIX/Linux/BSD). When that happens, the `__main__` module is imported (with a different name, so it doesn't try to *run* the main code again) in the child process to simulate a `fork`.

This mostly works, but it fails badly in the case of self-seeding PRNGs, because they reseed in the child process, and the globals are regenerated from that new PRNG, rather than having their generated values inherited by the child.

In short, the ways to make this work are:

1. Run it with `'fork'` as the `multiprocessing` start method (not possible on Windows, technically allowed on macOS, but could break, it's why they changed the default to `'spawn'`). I tested your code on Linux (where it `fork`s by default), and aside from fixing a typo (you typed `results` in one place where it should be `result`), `result` and `F` are the same there. When I add `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` just before creating the `Pool`, they don't match.
2. Explicitly pass an `initializer` function and arguments to `Pool` so each worker resets `F` to the value seen in the parent
3. Use an explicit seed before generating `F` so it's consistent no matter the process (downside: it'll be the same every run, or at least, *very* predictable, depending how clever you try to get)

Note that #2 and #3 can be combined to minimize dataflow. Generate a "real" random seed in the parent (e.g. with `os.urandom`) and write a simple function that accepts a seed and uses it to both seed the PRNG and generate `F` (using `global F` to let it change the global value). Call that function in the parent and pass it as the `initializer` with the seed argument to each child. Now, instead of passing the generated value of `F` (potentially huge), you only need to pass the seed, and the child process can reproduce `F` locally without needing to serialize the whole thing. Downside: All processes share the same random seed; it's not predictable like a hardcoded seed, but parents and children will be drawing from an identical set of random numbers.

Comment: On the other hand, *not* having the same RNG seed in every worker process is usually a good idea. Using the same RNG seed in every process leads to spurious correlations that can ruin your data. (I consider workers inheriting RNG seeds to be one of the big design flaws of `multiprocessing`.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: Yeah, ideally, the seed is different for every process, but `F` is the same (since it's logically the same value). Option #2 would get that result.

Comment: also this works in 3.6 because "spawn" was only changed to the default on MacOS in 3.8 onward. 3.6 uses "fork" by default

Comment: @Aaron: Yeah, the OP hadn't mentioned testing version 3.6 or the OS in question when I answered. Would have made the answer rather less psychic had either been specified. :-)